# Configure Spark and Hadoop separately (which version used of haddop with spark)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I am trying to configure spark 2.4.4 with hadoop 3.1.2, i have successfully install hadoop-3.1.2.tar.gz and spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop.tgz and i have builds conf/spark-env.sh file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk8u202-b08
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=($HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop classpath)
```

but when i start spark-shell

```
2019-11-27 11:53:07,051 WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, xxxxxxx resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 172.20.20.145 instead (on interface wlp2s0)
2019-11-27 11:53:07,052 WARN util.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
2019-11-27 11:53:07,327 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark context Web UI available at http://ashish-mittal:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1574835792826).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.4
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_202)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

**how to check which version used of hadoop with spark**

Comment: `master = local[*]` means that you are not using YARN, you launched Spark in standalone mode. I suggest you to install Hadoop and Spark using Apache Ambari.

Answer (score 0):

Spark uses HADOOP_HOME and loads the classpath from there, so the version you downloaded is the version it will use

Note that Spark does not yet fully support Hadoop3